# Sound Back on pavucontrol

Tags: sound, pavucontrol

I have soundback on my earphones, I hear the sounds of my environment. How repair that ? I use pavucontrol.

Thanks

Comment: "I hear the sounds of my environment" sounds like you are listening to a microphone. are you only hearing microphone, or do you also hear music and other sounds from pc? is this a laptop with built in microphone or desktop? do you have separate jack sockets for headphones and speakers or just one socket for both?

Comment: Hi nik, thank you for your answer, Yes I hear music and all, I have a two-in-one jacks sockets for my microphone, but two sockets on my pc availables.

Answer (score 0):

check your pc manual to make sure jack has headphone socket (3-way connection) or headset (4-way connection). 
only use jack plug with same number of connections or get an adaptor cable.

If the jack connections are ok but you still hear sound from microphone, it could be an internal laptop microphone. go to Pulseaudio Volume Control or alsamixer and mute microphones or other recording devices to find out which one is causing problem.
If the problem microphone is not used, leave it off.
If you need to use the microphone some of the time, need more details to  explain your problem better - with screenshots if you can